# Select data from table with compare two table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table.

table one name list

```
ID  device_id 

1      2

2      2

3      4
```

Table two name sync

```
ID  devide_id  list_id

1      4         2
```

Now if i want to select all data from list table for devide_id   then two row shown cause sync table devide_id  4 have a item.

I am trying this query

```
SELECT s.*
FROM list AS s,sync AS sc
WHERE s.device_id = 4 AND sc.device_id=4 AND sc.list_id=s.id
```

But Not Work

expected result

For device_id 4

```
ID  device_id 

 3      4

 2      2
```

For device_id 2

```
ID  device_id 

1      2

2      2
```

Comment: what is your expected result set ?

Comment: try with `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Try this
select * from list as l LEFT JOIN sync as s WHERE l.device_id = s.device_id WHERE l.device_id = 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can see to get your first example is to use something like this:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM list AS s,sync AS sc
WHERE s.device_id = 4 OR (sc.device_id=4 AND sc.list_id=s.id)
```

(Note: not tested, may need tweaking)

because your example out put has *either* device-id of 4 *OR* it gets the device-id of 4 from the sync table.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have asked the question is bit hard to figure out. The way I understood is,

You want to retrieve all the data from table **List** having a condition on **device_id**

But there will be just one record will be displayed according to your table.

If it's possible please revise the question so that we can understand it easily.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Sorry. I actually wanted to comment but as I don't have 50 reputations I'm not able to comment. That's why I made it as an answer.

Comment: @KingFeming you shouldn't write it as an answer though :( we want to try and keep answers as answers and comments as comments for when others come by to get an answer

Comment: @JohnRuddell Sure.. I'll have it in my practice. Thanks for the advice :)